# Less oxygen in winter?

Tags: trees

Since Oxygen is produced by photosynthesis, would there be less oxygen in the air in winter, where the trees shed their leaves and the sun generally shines a lot less? If yes, would that be a noticable difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty interesting question: The short answer to it is: Yes, the seasonal O<sub>2</sub> levels vary with the season and this can be measured.
The paper in reference 1 says that this is connected to two phenomena: Production of O<sub>2</sub> by photosynthesis and also the uptake and release of O<sub>2</sub> in the oceans due to higher temperatures (warmer water dissolves less gases).

The paper in reference 2 says that the northern and the southern hemisphere are basically decoupled from each other. The northern hemisphere reaches its peak of maximum O<sub>2</sub> concentration in June/July while the southern reaches its peak around January due to the slow mixing in the athmosphere. They also say that due to more ocean area on the southern hemisphere the uptake/release processes in the ocean play a much more important role there.

The graph from paper 3 also shows that the CO<sub>2</sub> concentration is inverse compared to O<sub>2</sub>, since during the photosynthetic period of the year CO<sub>2</sub> is consumed.

[image]

The following figure is taken from the website of "2° Institute" and is interactive, so can actually check, when the concentration is at which level. The general O<sub>2</sub> concentration is getting lower, it is assumed that this happens due to the human CO<sub>2</sub> production, the source can be found [here](https://www.oxygenlevels.org/).

[image]

References (please let me know in the comments, if you can't access the articles):

1. [Seasonal and interannual variations in atmospheric oxygen and
   implications for the global carbon cycle](https://www.nature.com/articles/358723a0)
2. [Seasonal variations in the atmospheric O2/N2 ratio in relation to the  kinetics of air-sea gas exchange](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/97GB02339)
3. [Seasonal and short-term variations in atmospheric potential oxygen
   at Ny- Ålesund, Svalbard](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/16000889.2017.1311767)